# Bash is abnormal in Makefile!

Tags: bash, makefile, make

all,

I have found that the same Makefile works well in Mac OS X, but does not work in Ubuntu. The snippet is as following:

```
start:
    @echo $(seperator)
    @if [[ "$(PROJECT)" == "" ]]; then \
         echo " Project powered by CodeMate!"; \
     else \
         echo "  $(PROJECT)"; \
     fi
    @echo $(seperator)
```

and *make* complains:

```
/bin/sh: [[: not found
```

Any idea?

Cheers,

Li

---

Updates:

I have changed the above conditional Bash statements to:

```
if test "$(PROJECT)" = ""; then \
```

then things work fine. So what is wrong with "[["?

Comment: Same goes for `printf %q`, dash has a builtin that does not support `%q`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Makefiles use `sh` by default, not `bash`.

In Ubuntu `sh` point to `dash`, a POSIX compliant and minimalistic shell, not providing the `[[` keywork.

Comment: So we should limit the scripts in the Makefile. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Place this at the top of your `Makefile`:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash # Use bash syntax
```

This happens because `[[` is a builtin command of `bash` and you're running it with `sh`. The above line will set `bash` as default interpreter for the commands ran on makefile.