# Bash can't read glob pattern

Tags: command-line, bash, pdf

I'm trying to make my CV build script run on Ubuntu. I usually use Fedora to build it. Each page is written in SVG, I use Inkscape to generate PDF and then pdfmerge to join those pages into one.

On Ubuntu I can't find pdfmerge so I wanted to change it to pdfunite. But it seems the command doesn't accept the glob patterns. It should be handled by the shell:

```
pdfunite pl/jakub-jankiewicz-cv-page{1,2,3}.pdf jakub-jankiewicz-cv-pl.pdf
I/O Error: Couldn't open file 'pl/jakub-jankiewicz-cv-page{1,2,3}.pdf': No such file or directory.
Syntax Error: Could not merge damaged documents ('pl/jakub-jankiewicz-cv-page{1,2,3}.pdf')
make: *** [Makefile:22: jakub-jankiewicz-cv-pl.pdf] Błąd 255
```

This is the code I have in my Makefile:

```
jakub-jankiewicz-cv-pl.pdf: pl/jakub-jankiewicz-cv-page1.pdf pl/jakub-jankiewicz-cv-page2.pdf pl/jakub-jankiewicz-cv-page3.pdf
    pdfunite pl/jakub-jankiewicz-cv-page{1,2,3}.pdf jakub-jankiewicz-cv-pl.pdf
```

Why I can't use a glob pattern like {1,2,3} on Ubuntu? I have Xubuntu 22.04 and bash `5.1.16(1)-release` the same code works fine on Fedora.

Comment: Don't run it from a Makefile ... Run it in the terminal directly `pdfunite pl/jakub-jankiewicz-cv-page{1,2,3}.pdf jakub-jankiewicz-cv-pl.pdf` and the pattern should be expanded.

Comment: @Raffa yes, running directly works but I want to use Makefile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{1,2,3}` isn't a [glob pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#index-filename-expansion) - it's a [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#index-brace-expansion). Likely the issue is not that *"bash can't read"* it - it's that the `make` command uses the POSIX `/bin/sh` shell by default, which on Ubuntu is symbolically linked to `/bin/dash` rather than `/bin/bash.` Your options are either:

1. change the brace expansion to an actual (POSIX compliant) glob - for a single digit, that's straightforward i.e. `pl/jakub-jankiewicz-cv-page[123].pdf`
2. change the shell in your Makefile to bash, by adding `SHELL := /bin/bash`

See also [Bash is abnormal in Makefile!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95365/bash-is-abnormal-in-makefile).

Comment: I would never figure this out. Thanks.